# confusing date manipulations

Tags: php, date

tying to go through all sundays like this:

```
/*self::WEEK = 604800*/
/* 3600 * 24 * 7 looks like 7 days for me*/


    $start = 1286053200;
    for ($i=0; $i < 10; $i++) {
        echo date('d.m.Y H:i:s.u, D (z)', $start) . ' (' . $start . ')<br/>';
        $start += self::WEEK;
    }
```

but in some case i see this:

```
03.10.2010 00:00:00.000000, Sun (275) (1286053200)
10.10.2010 00:00:00.000000, Sun (282) (1286658000)
17.10.2010 00:00:00.000000, Sun (289) (1287262800)
24.10.2010 00:00:00.000000, Sun (296) (1287867600)
31.10.2010 00:00:00.000000, Sun (303) (1288472400)
06.11.2010 23:00:00.000000, Sat (309) (1289077200) <--
13.11.2010 23:00:00.000000, Sat (316) (1289682000)
20.11.2010 23:00:00.000000, Sat (323) (1290286800)
27.11.2010 23:00:00.000000, Sat (330) (1290891600)
04.12.2010 23:00:00.000000, Sat (337) (1291496400)
```

in other words lost an hour!? where?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try strtotime()

```
$start = 1286053200;
for ($i=0; $i < 10; $i++) {
    echo date('d.m.Y H:i:s.u, D (z)', strtotime(' +' . ($i * 7) . ' DAYS',$start)) . ' (' . $start . ')<br/>';
}
```

Comment: `strtotime("+".$i." week", $start);` looks better $-)

Comment: Updated with SubDigger's suggestion. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[Daylight saving?](http://www.timeanddate.com/time/dst/2010.html)

Try [`gmdate()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gmdate.php) instead.

Comment: in witch way i shall use gmdate? how can i fix my problems?

Comment: @Subdigger: `gmdate` works on GMT, which doesn't have daylight saving.

Comment: change to this: `echo gmdate('d.m.Y H:i:s.u, D (z)', $start + 3600 * 2) . ' (' . $start . ')<br/>';` does not helps. can you show an example

Answer (score 0):

I created a function for a [similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7395706/get-the-date-of-all-fridays-in-php). Maybe you'll find it useful.

```
function getDays($year, $dayofweek, $format, $timezone='UTC')
{
    $fridays = array();
    $startDate = new DateTime("{$year}-01-01 {$dayofweek}", new DateTimezone($timezone));
    $year++;
    $endDate = new DateTime("{$year}-01-01", new DateTimezone($timezone));
    $int = new DateInterval('P7D');
    foreach(new DatePeriod($startDate, $int, $endDate) as $d) {
        $fridays[] = $d->format($format);
    }

    return $fridays;
}

$sundays = getDays('2010', 'Sunday', 'd.m.Y H:i:s.u, D (z)', 'America/New_York');
var_dump($sundays);
```